# How to make edit controls have 3D look?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I created an edit control by the following code:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowExW( 0,      // extended styles
                        L"EDIT",
                        L"Text in edit.",
                        ES_LEFT | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                        10,     // x
                        50,     // y
                        30,     // width
                        100,    // height
                        hWndMainWindow,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL);
```

My edit control looks like this:
[image: My edit control]

But most edit controls I see in Windows have a 3D look like in the image below:
[image: Normal edit controls]

I tried several extended and normal window styles, but the didn't do any good. How do I make my edit control look like in the second image?

Some quick links that may help you to take reference:
[Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/czada357.aspx)
[Extended Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/61fe4bte.aspx)
[Edit Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6e36b89f.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` extended window style.

You say that you have already tried including `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE` without success. I'm going to take a wild guess that you have been trying to include it in the window style rather than the extended window style. Your code should look like this:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowExW( 
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,  // extended styles
    L"EDIT",
    ...
);
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, then it must be something else in your program that is changing the style. Because the difference between the two controls in your screenshots is the presence or otherwise of `WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE`.